# C++20 functional-style function calls

Tags: c++, functional-programming, template-specialization, c++20

I have been recently struggling to achieve a way of calling functions in a functional (piped) style such as given a function `foo(int, float)` can be called in such way `10 | foo(10.f)` .

(Assuming the pipe operator here, which can actually be random)

This is as far as I've gotten

```
string _add(int&& a1, int&& a2)
{
    return "ADD i:" + to_string(a1) + " i:" + to_string(a2);
}

string _add(float&& a1, int&& a2)
{
    return "ADD f:" + to_string(a1) + " i:" + to_string(a2);
}

string _add(int&& a1, float&& a2)
{
    return "ADD i:" + to_string(a1) + " f:" + to_string(a2);
}

struct add_name;
template <typename SUBJ, typename A1>
auto operator|(SUBJ subj, args<add_name, A1, monostate> args)
{
    return _add(move(subj), move(args.a1));
}
template <typename A1> using add = args<add_name, A1, monostate>;
```

where `args` is a template structure to hold arguments.
This allows me to invoke the functions like this

```
string s1 = 10.f | add(15);
string s2 = 10 | add(15);
string s3 = 10 | add(10.f);
```

Eventually there is a macro that generates the templates for each function name and I am able to use this quite successfully.
Also, this works very well for overloads and function templates.

There is, however a huge drawback to this, i.e all function specializations need to be known prior the definition of the operator template.

It makes it more and more challenging to use, while the codebase grows.

I've been back and forth with different ideas, but there are C++ limitations that does not allow me to implement this the way it would be much more useful, including

1. no way of passing a function name down the template specialization chain
2. C++ complaining about (re)defining the exact same template

Is there a way to achieve function pipelining as described above ?

Comment: Not clear what you want, what is `args`.

Comment: Can't you use functor (with overload `operator()`) instead of functions.

Comment: *"no way of passing a function name"*, passing overload set is indeed not possible by name, but lambda can be used for that.

Comment: At the global scope `_add` is a reserved symbol.  May be something that is causing some issue.

Comment: I've flagged this as _needs more details_. It needs a reproducible example. At least.

Answer (score 1):

> all function specializations need to be known prior the definition of the operator template.

For builtin and non-dependant type, yes.
For dependent type, ADL might help.

> no way of passing a function name down the template specialization chain

Passing overloads set cannot be passed by name, but can be by lambda.

> C++ complaining about (re)defining the exact same template

You have tag, to allow your different overload, so it shouldn't be problematic.

But, you might write only one `operator|` if you provide Functor as template parameter, something like:

```
template <auto, typename T>
struct Args
{
    Args(T data) : data(std::move(data)) {}
    
    T data;  
};

template <typename LHS, auto F, typename T>
auto operator|(LHS&& lhs, Args<F, T> rhs)
{
    return F(std::forward<LHS>(lhs), std::move(rhs.data));
}
```

then

```
// Your overloads
std::string _add(int&& a1, int&& a2)
{
    return "ADD i:" + std::to_string(a1) + " i:" + std::to_string(a2);
}

std::string _add(float&& a1, int&& a2)
{
    return "ADD f:" + std::to_string(a1) + " i:" + std::to_string(a2);
}

std::string _add(int&& a1, float&& a2)
{
    return "ADD i:" + std::to_string(a1) + " f:" + std::to_string(a2);
}

// The alias
template <typename T>
using add = Args<[](auto&& lhs, auto&& rhs){ return _add((decltype(lhs))lhs, (decltype(rhs))rhs); }, T>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/80c76cc5373a83fb).

Comment: Extended the args a bit to match multiple parameters and it works like a charm. I did not know `std::forward` could be used in this way. Thanks very much, glad to learn something new :3

Comment: Although it still requires defining the functions prior the aliases, otherwise their use results in 'not declared' error such as `error: ‘_add’ was not declared in this scope`.
Currently trying to make my way so that I provide proper include order, although I see that as quite problematic.

Comment: at the same time redeclaring the alias raises an 'conficting declaration' error, so I am not able to redefine it every time I declare an overload, though not sure if it would be the right way of addressing this at all

Comment: As I said, with builtin/ non dependent types, you need to respect order. there are tricks as `adl_tag` to enable ADL.

Answer (score 0):

Just make `operator|` generic:

```
template<typename LeftT, typename RightT>
auto operator|(LeftT&& left, RightT&& right)
-> decltype(std::forward<RightT>(right)(std::forward<LeftT>(left)))
{return std::forward<RightT>(right)(std::forward<LeftT>(left));}
```

Now This allows you to `value | single_arg_method` for any value and unary functionoid in the entire codebase.  (Though this will complicate your compiler errors any time you have a typo near a an innocent `|`)

Then the only trick is to make `add(15)` generate the desired unary functionoid. I was unable to think of a way to do this without macros to give this functionoid the same name as the method it called.

```
#define define_bifunction_to_monofunction(name) \
template<class ArgT> \
auto name(ArgT&& right) { \
    return [&right](auto&& left){ \
        return _ ## name(std::forward<decltype(left)>(left), std::forward<ArgT>(right)); \
    }; \
}
```

(Someone with more knowledge than I of macros might now how to use `##` to get it to call `_add` instead of `add`)

Now the usage ends up simple:

```
string _add(int&& a1, float&& a2)
{
    return "ADD i:" + to_string(a1) + " f:" + to_string(a2);
}
define_bifunction_to_monofunction(add)

int main() {
    string s1 = 10.f | add(15);
    string s2 = 10 | add(15);
    string s3 = 10 | add(10.f);
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/30697aebc0d594ac

However, this does make the `operator|` overly aggressive, which can lead to strange compiler errors, so it's usually recommended to make some sort of type flag, which complicates the implementation slightly:

```
template<typename FunctionT>
struct enabled_pipe_chaining : std::false_type {};

template<typename LeftT, typename RightT, typename enabled=std::enable_if_t<enabled_pipe_chaining<RightT>::value,void> >
auto operator|(LeftT&& left, RightT&& right)
{return std::forward<RightT>(right)(std::forward<LeftT>(left));}

#define enable_mono_pipe_chain(name) \
template<> struct enabled_pipe_chaining<decltype(name)> : std::true_type {};

#define define_bifunction_pipe_chain(name) \
template<typename RightT> \
struct name ## _pipe_chainable { \
    RightT&& right; \
    template<typename LeftT> \
    auto operator()(LeftT&& left) { \
        return _ ## name(std::forward<decltype(left)>(left), std::forward<RightT>(right)); \
    } \
}; \
template<typename RightT> struct enabled_pipe_chaining<name ## _pipe_chainable<RightT>> : std::true_type {}; \
template<typename RightT> \
name ## _pipe_chainable<RightT> name(RightT&& right) { return {std::forward<RightT>(right)};}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41ce66c1a1444495

But then the `operator|` will *only* be available for pipe_chainable methods, rather than any `operator|` in the code.

Comment: [`_ ## name`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28b2911f8ee3ea89)?

Comment: I would avoid generic function, which might conflict/prohibit other custom `operator|`, better to create custom wrapper type IMO.

Comment: @Jarod42 I would too, but it makes things drastically more complicated. Done anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Clang will tell you what the problem is with declaring the overloads after the template:

```
error: call to function '_add' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
    return _add(move(subj), move(args.a1));
           ^
```

The simplest solution is to enable argument-dependent lookup by passing a tag type:

```
struct adl_tag {};
template <typename SUBJ, typename A1>
auto operator|(SUBJ subj, args<add_name, A1, monostate> args)
{
    return _add(adl_tag{}, move(subj), move(args.a1));
}
string _add(adl_tag, int&& a1, int&& a2)
// etc.
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/5jYzjq).